# How do I get the fancybox frame width, when it's done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a fancybox popup that expands to 95% of the parent

```
 $.fancybox.open({width:95%, ...
```

Is it at all possible to get the width of either the popup frame or the parent (both I need inside the popup frame) as I'll need to resize one part of the screen to hold an image with set width, when the image is large.

Answer (score 1):

You can select its parent with $(this).parent() and then ask for its width.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This will give you the outer width
$("#fancyBox_Container").outerWidth(); 

//This will give you parent outer width, in place of id, you can give direct element id or class name
$("#fancyBox_Container").parents().outerWidth();
```